# Spring Boot plugin was not found

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I have an issue with gradle project

My `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(
                "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

When I try to run build.gralde, I'm getting error

```
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.1.8.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:
```

Gradle preferences in IDEA

[image]

I can't understand, what is the problem, I've generated project with Spring Initializer

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and importing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I've got the problem.
You just need to turn off "Offline Mode" and it will download it from repo
[image]

It's in the right side of the Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation is that by configuring explicitly the `buildscript.repositories`, you no longer have the default `gradlePluginPortal()`.
Not all plugins are available on Maven Central for example.